# Laravel routes are not found in 000webhost

Tags: php, laravel, routes, cpanel

I'm building a simple blog for my personal projects with Laravel 5.4.36. I have uploaded it to `000webhost`. The problem is everytime I`m trying to sign up or sign in, it is saying,

> The requested URL was not found on this server

Here is the URL that is shown during this error,

```
https://myprojectblog.000webhostapp.com/signUp
```

Here 'signUp' or 'signIn' are provided in the routes file which are given below,

```
Route::post('/signUp', [
    'uses'=>'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as'=>'signUp' 
]);

Route::post('/signIn', [
    'uses'=>'UserController@postSignIn',
    'as'=>'signIn' 
]);
```

The sign up form is given below,

```
<div class="signUp">

        <label>Sign Up</label></br>

        <form action="{{ route('signUp') }}" method="POST" name="signUp" id="signUp">
            <label id="usernameLabelSignUp">Username</label></br>
            <input type="text" id="usernameSignUp" name="username" value="{{ Request::old('username')}}"></br>
            <label id="emailLabelSignUp">Email</label></br>
            <input type="text" id="emailSignUp" name="email" value="{{ Request::old('email')}}"></br>
            <label id="passwordLabelSignUp">Password</label></br>
            <input type="password" id="passwordSignUp" name="password"></br>            
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            <input type="submit" id="signUpSubmit" value="signUp">
        </form></br>

    </div>
```

In the cpanel of 000webhost my file structure is,

```
/
  -Blog

      -All the Laravel project directories and files except public 

  -public_html

      -public
            -css
            -js
            -.htacess
            -index.php
            -favicon.ico
            -robots.txt
            -web.config
```

My index.php in /public_html/public got included these lines,

```
require __DIR__.'/../Blog/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../Blog/bootstrap/app.php';
```

The index page loads without any trouble, but while trying to sign in or up the error occurs.

Most importantly everything runs absolutely fine in my local machine, no trouble at all.

Some clue would mean great help. Thank you.

Comment: Did you upload the `.htaccess` file? Is `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: I uploaded .htaccess, it contains 3 lines 


# HTID:5358805: DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW
php_value display_errors 1
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE HTID:5358805:

Comment: Hello i really help you in this problem. I faced this before there is nothing   can you tell me this server is lenux server or not ?

Comment: if yes then you need to enable rewrite mode  and allow rewrite to the you project directory i tell you how to do this but first you give me ans

Comment: My local PC is Ubuntu, but I`m facing the trouble in 000webhost.com

Comment: That would be really helpful if you give me some clue about mod_rewrite.

Comment: I have added RewriteEngine On to my .htaccess, still does not work.

Comment: Your `.htaccess` file should have much more content than just the 3 lines you've mentioned. Upload the file from the [Laravel repo](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess), and add the three lines from your existing file at the top.